# Subject of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a homework question which I don't know if my solution is correct

I need to isolate $l$ to one side of the equation

$$M = \frac w2 (L - l^2)$$

**MY SOLUTION**

$2M = w (L - l^2)$

$2M = Lw - wl^2$

$wl^2 = Lw - 2M$

$l^2 = \frac{Lw - 2M}w$

$l = \sqrt{\frac{Lw - 2M}w}$

Thanks

Comment: If all you have to do is isolate the variable $l$ then your calculations look good so long as $w\neq 0$. If however you need to find all the solutions for $l$ then you may want to check your answer against the quadratic equation since your equation is quadratic in $l$.

Comment: When you divide the right hand side by $w$ you have to assume that $w\neq0$ and keep in mind that when taking the square root of a squared expression like $x^2=y+2$ then the solution is $+\sqrt{y+2}$ **and** $-\sqrt{y+2}$. However, the manipulations look good.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is OK, but I think you should rewrite the last term of the solution as: $$l = +\sqrt{\frac{Lw - 2M}w} \lor l = -\sqrt{\frac{Lw - 2M}w}$$